# Constructor from a reference to array not selected for list initialisation

Tags: c++, c++17, list-initialization

Given the following struct:

```
struct A {
    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    A(T const(&array)[N]) {}

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    A& operator=(T const(&array)[N]) { return *this; }
 };
```

The code:

```
// a is of type A
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

compiles just fine, since `std::initialiser_list` is implicitly converted to an array reference.

However,

```
A a {1, 2, 3, 4};
A a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

fails to compile with both Clang and GCC. It does compile when I add a constructor that accepts a `std::initialiser_list<T>`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't even think a struct could have constructors and operators.  It must be part of some newer standard.  Does it work if you use "A a({1, 2, 3, 4});" instead of "A a {1, 2, 3, 4};" ?

Comment: Or also `A a{{1, 2, 3, 4}}`?

Comment: @BobShaffer `struct` and `class` have been practically synonymous in C++ for very long time (I think even from the start?). I prefer `struct` to `class` in most cases since I almost never use traditional OOP in my programs.

Comment: `A a ({1, 2, 3, 4});` and `A a {{1, 2, 3, 4}};` both work but I am still confused by the asymmetry to the assignment operator. Why is the initialiser list implicitly converted in one case but not in the other?

Comment: @BobShaffer `struct`s could always have constructors. The only difference between `class` and `struct` is what the default access is (`private` vs `public`)

Comment: Pulled out my C++ reference from the 90s and, of course, you are correct.  The only difference between struct and class is that all members are public in a struct.  I don't even think it said all public, but "by default" like it was shorthand for "class T{public:" it said.  So, yeah, from the beginning this has been true and I never realized it.

Comment: I also didn't think you could initialize anything as you show in your example: I thought things like **int a 5;** or **char *s "foo";** or even **int foo[2] {0,1};** were all invalid.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @BobShaffer C++11 introduced consistent uniform object initialisation  — https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization Some very useful discussion here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax

Comment: I don't see much value in this form of construction to be quite honest.  It looks like the kind of thing that would cause unexpected things to happen frequently, like what happened to you here.  All for the sake of saving one =.  Still, I always appreciate learning new things while I am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need extra braces or parens:

```
A a{{1, 2, 3, 4}}; // ok
A b({1, 2, 3, 4}); // ok
```

The reason for this is the outer braces/parens are for the `A` and in the inner braces are for the `array` object that you're list-initializing.

With assignment, you don't need the extra parens or braces because they're simply implied by the function call:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

is equivalent to:

```
a.operator=({1, 2, 3, 4});
```

More or less.

---

> It does compile when I add a constructor that accepts a `std::initialiser_list<T>`.

To elaborate on how list-initialization works. When you write `A a{1, 2, 3, 4}`, we're looking *first* for some `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor (which we don't have yet, and so don't find one) and then look for a constructor that we can call with four arguments (which doesn't exist). Adding the extra `()`s or `{}`s means we're looking for a constructor that we can call with *one* argument which we initialize with `1, 2 ,3, 4`.

Once you add the `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor, now that's a viable candidate for that first phase of initialization.

---

Note that this:

> compiles just fine, since `std::initialiser_list` is implicitly converted to an array reference.

is not right. There is no `std::initializer_list` anywhere in this question. `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is a funny thing in C++. It doesn't have a type or anything. It's just a *braced-init-list*. It's only based on context that we give it meaning. In this case, it's not a thing that's converted to a different thing... it's just a collection of initializers for the array.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I was totally confused by the relationship between the array and the `std::initialiser_list`.